# Alternative to sun.misc.Signal

Tags: java, signals, compatibility, sun

I started research to find an alternative to the `sun.misc.Signal` class, because it could be unsupported in upcoming JDKs (we're currently working on 1.6). When I build the project I get:

> warning: sun.misc.SignalHandler is Sun proprietary API and may be
>   removed in a future release

I came across multiple solutions but they don't fit my project e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023520/sending-signals-to-a-running-jvm).

This is unacceptable in my situation because:

- Signals are used not only for killing application
- The application is huge - every conceptual change of communication between modules/JVMs could take years to implement

Thus, the desirable solution is to find something like a new Oracle version of this class or something which works in the same way. Does such a solution exist?

Comment: Do you know that it is not supporting Java 8 or 9?  Given Java rarely ever removes anything, is this a real concern?

Comment: If there is any possibility to not supporting this I can't take a risk. Like I said before - it is huge application and every possible fail connected to this problem could be disaster for whole project :)

Comment: Your concern is that someone will change the JVM to Java 9 in production without any thought, testing or warning and then blame you if it doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you are right but my concern is to solve problem, not to 'hack' them or act like there is no problem.

Comment: I am not clear what the problem is if you have sensible release processes.  If you don't this is the true problem worth solving.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture SIGINT in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541475/capture-sigint-in-java)

Comment: If you don't mind changing how you launch the VM, using JNI and only targeting  **Hotspot** VMs then it's possible to use [Signal Chaining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/handle-signals-and-exceptions.htm#GUID-CB49A2A7-2A9F-4C18-948F-6D4A96FF688D).

Answer (score 29):

As you will find repeated ad infinitum when learning about signal handling in Java, you are encouraged to avoid writing Java code that depends directly on signals.  The general best practice is to allow the JVM to exit normally on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and other signals by registering a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html) instead. Handling signals directly makes your Java program OS-dependent.

But sometimes that's OK, and you really, really do want to handle signals yourself.

Even though it's not exposed as part of the official JDK API, some part of the JVM has to handle signals (in order to trigger the shutdown hooks and exit), and that component is `sun.misc.Signal`. Although this is an implementation detail and therefore *could* change, it is unlikely in practice.  If it were to change, it would need to be replaced with an equivalent mechanism, and likely documented in the [Java Platform Troubleshooting Guide](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/signals.html).

The sibling class `sun.misc.Unsafe` is widely used and is [similarly undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819234/where-is-sun-misc-unsafe-documented). There is active work towards trying to remove this class because it's "[become a 'dumping ground' for non-standard, yet necessary, methods](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GDm_cAxYInmoHMor-AkStzWvwE9pw6tnz_CebJQxuUE/edit)", but the [current proposal](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260), while limiting some non-standard APIs, keeps both `sun.misc.Unsafe` and `sun.misc.Signal` available by default. An earlier plan to actually prevent access to these classes would still have included a command-line flag to allow access to them for backwards-compatibility.

In short while you *cannot* rely on `sun.misc.Signal` and *must* plan for the eventuality that this behavior changes, it is *highly unlikely* that this behavior will change before JDK 10, and if it does either a new, better mechanism will *probably* be introduced or there will be a reasonable way to re-enable it if needed.

However it would be wise to compartmentalize the code that relies on any `sun.misc` classes to as small a scope as possible - create a wrapping API for signal handling so that callers don't need to interact directly with `sun.misc`. That way if the API changes you only need to change the implementation of your wrapper, rather than all your signal handling code.

Comment: @specializt care to share a citation or reference? It's still in the head revision of [JDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Signal.java) and JEP 260 still indicates `sun.misc.{Signal,SignalHandler}` will "*remain accessible in JDK 9*". Even if the plan for JDK 9 had changed it would be very strange at this point for them to remove it from the already- released JDK 8.

Comment: Update -  `sun.misc.Signal` is alive and well in JDK 11, and I can't find anything indicating any current plans for removal.

Comment: Another update: `sun.misc.Signal` is still available in JDK 16

Answer (score 4):

Such a solution does exist. JNR ( https://github.com/jnr/ ) is an efficient POSIX layer; comparison with JNI+JNA I read here: https://www.slideshare.net/skrb/jnr-java-native-runtime .

This is my code to handle SIGHUP in Java using JNR:

```
SignalHandler handler = new SignalHandler()
    {
    @Override public void handle(int signal)  { reloadThings(); }
    };
final POSIX posix = POSIXFactory.getPOSIX(new DefaultPOSIXHandler(), true);
posix.signal(Signal.SIGHUP, handler);
```

The SignalHandler code is what will be done, the posix Handle is the JNR entry point AFAIK, and then the last line registers the signal.

JNR seems to be under active development (as of 2021), and isn't too large. Looks good to me - I just started using it because of this.
PS: I just checked this to work with SIGINT = Ctrl+C. It does.

Comment: Very nice, just add one dependency `com.github.jnr:jnr-posix` and copy your snippet and it works. Just for CTRL+C/SIGINT, I had to set `useNativePOSIX` of `POSIXFactory#getPOSIX` to `false`, at least on Linux, otherwise the signal was trapped but the handler not executed.

Answer (score -13):

Your best bet is to transition away from signals since they are not well supported.

Alternatives for IPC:

- Sockets (including web services, JMS, etc)
- File locking
- Memory mapped file

Comment: None of those alternatives can be used to e.g. handle a SIGTERM (Ctrl-C) in a console application