# Regarding JVM signal handling

Tags: java, linux, process, jvm, shutdown

I want to disable signals like `SIGINT`, which is sent by pressing CTRL_C, and also other signals which will terminates JVM. I read about **-Xrs option** here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html?cm_mc_uid=30731201786714525992590&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1461656557

But it seems to have no effect on JVM/process termination.
I launched the program jar like `java -Xrs -jar avoid-signals.jar`.

I am on linux.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I suspect it's not possible to do properly - SIGKILL, for example, can't simply be caught and ignored - it *will* cause the process to terminate unless its in uninterruptable sleep, either way the process isn't going to do anything useful after receiving a SIGKILL.

Comment: fix wordings, markers

Comment: Duplicate; linking to my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/67852569/448779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Xrs says

> Reduces use of operating-system signals by the Java VM.

That means the JVM only installs fewer of its own signal handlers. Fewer signal handlers simply mean that more signals are handled through their [default action](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Which in many cases results in process termination.

Signals can either be suppressed through a [signal mask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html), processed through a [signal handler](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) or various other means.

Currently the JDK offers no public APIs, but you can either use internal, unsupported ones (`sun.misc.SignalHandler`) or [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/blob/5b2827939d15731e4aa851552a336e957fedef31/src/test/java/jnr/posix/SignalTest.java).

Or if you mostly care about Ctrl+C and other keystrokes and not really the signals themselves you can detach the java process from the console via `nohup java -jar ... > /dev/null &`