# Unable to catch interrupt in java command line program

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How could I “intercept” Ctrl+C in a CLI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216172/java-how-could-i-intercept-ctrlc-in-a-cli-application)

On Windows I start a java non gui application doing a task
Then press CNTL-C and the program just exits, none of my interrupt handling code seems to trigger, even putting a try/catch in the main method never displays a stack trace to indicate it has been interuppted.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
         CmdLineDecoder cld = new CmdLineDecoder();
         cld.start(args);
         System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding the effect of Cntl-C, but what ?

Comment: Does `CmdLineDecoder.start` throw an `InterruptedException`?

Comment: But what ... what?  Did you mean to close like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216172/java-how-could-i-intercept-ctrlc-in-a-cli-application

Comment: @Jeffrey no doesn't seem to because should output a System.out.println message if recewives such an exception

Comment: Seems like this is a dup, so it would be more constructive to vote up the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216172/java-how-could-i-intercept-ctrlc-in-a-cli-application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do general signal handling in java, but you can handle <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd>.

If you need to do something upon VM shutdown, use a shutdown hook: [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

From the docs:

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
>
> The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

I've used this in the past on Windows/OSX.

Comment: hmm, sounds like this occurs after the event. What I want to happen is for my CmdLineDecoders finally block (not shown) to actually run  becfore my application shutsdown

Comment: okay I think i can work with this, thanks.