# How to stop/terminate java program by pressing Ctrl+C & Ctrl+Alt+Del for window plateform?

Tags: java, performance, console, window, console-application

I want to `terminate` my current `Java Program's Execution` as like,

```
System.exit(0);
```

while user press either one of following `key-combination` from `key-board`,

```
 1. Ctrl+C

 2. Ctrl+Alt+Del
```

I have searched a lot but nothing seems to be `correct`. 
if possible then please provide me a fruitful code snippet too.

*thank you, :-)*

Comment: where do you run your program? cmd or eclipse

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0); u try this

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal how Runtime.getRuntime.exit(0); will capture my Ctrl+C key from key-board ? i want while my program runs infinity and in between Ctrl+C press and terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for [Shutdown hooks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html) in java

Check this answers to cook your code :) [How can I "intercept" Ctrl+C in a CLI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216172/how-can-i-intercept-ctrlc-in-a-cli-application)

Comment: have you try & execute what actually provided by them?

Comment: yes, we always write shutdownhooks in all application so we can handle `SIGHUP` or `Ctrl+C`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can terminate the java.exe running process by above code

Comment: this is not suitable with what i asked.